# Azure AD Self-Service Sign Up Fetch Manager Information

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I am looking to setup a self-service signup portal for Azure AD B2B. Only information that's populated during the sign up is Email, Given Name and Surname.

I am looking to auto-fetch some other field like manager, job title, etc. Is there a way I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Created a **user flow** in Azure AD:

[image]

> I am looking to auto-fetch some other field like manager, job title, etc. Is there a way I can do this.

To populate the custom attributes during sign up, **you can add custom attributes** refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/customers/how-to-define-custom-attributes):

*Go to Microsoft Entra ID -> External Identities -> Custom user attributes -> Add*

[image]

Now *go to User flows -> Select your User flow -> User attributes -> Select the custom attribute*

[image]

I used **Postman** to test the same:

```json
Auth URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Access Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID : ClientID
Client Secret : ClientSecret
Scope : user.read
```

[image]

When I clicked on Create account, **I got the custom attribute populated during sign in** like below:

[image]

The user got created successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Add custom attributes to self-service sign-up flows - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/user-flow-add-custom-attributes)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is not what I am exactly looking for. I want this field to be auto-populated during the self-service signup process like First Name, Last Name and Full Name gets populated.